# Как обновлять DataTable через Ajax jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, html5

Есть `html` форма, внутри нее находится `datatable` c `tr` и `td`, в которых хранятся значения полученный из БД. Как обновлять таблицу, допустим через каждые 5 секунд, без разницы что-то добавилось или нет, пусть обновляется. Как такое реализовать с помощью `ajax` и `jquery`?

Comment: вам слабо воспользоваться поиском по сайту? таких вопросов тут сотни. ваш вопрос — не уникален

Comment: Алексей Здраствуйте .На самом деле я посмотрел но большая часть из них относятся к DataTables подключаемый из вне .а я использую встроенный .Я прежде чем спросить , искал

Comment: что такое datatable? такого тега нет в HTML.